# Can I notch a fig tree to promote branching?

Tags: pruning, figs, espalier

I have a small garden. One area that gets a lot of sun is along a fence, so I decided to try an espaliered fig tree. My problem is that the tree doesn’t have many branches low down. Is there anything I can do to promote branching around 18-24" above the ground?

I know with fiddle-leaf figs (same genus, different species), you can cut little notches above nodes to prompt branching. Does that work on Mission Figs?

(I should note that I do want the main trunk to continue growing up for a while, so I don’t want to cut that yet. The answer may be to wait for it to reach the height I want, then cut the tip before trying to promote branches.)

Comment: I have a regular fig tree and it requires vigorous pruning ( 25 % ) to get new wood for fruiting. If yours is like my tree you could prune the top branches a hope some new growth would start low.